# SelectSingleNode and SelectNodes XPath syntax

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

My question is very similar to this one [XmlNode.SelectSingleNode syntax to search within a node in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950032/xmlnode-selectsinglenode-syntax-to-search-within-a-node-in-c-sharp)

I'm trying to use HTML Agility Pack to pull price/condition/ship price...  Here's the URL I am scraping: http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0470108541/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8&condition=all

Here's a snippet of my code:

---

```
    string results = "";
    var w = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = w.Load(url);
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-medium olpOffer']");

    if (nodes != null)
    {
         foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
         {
              var price = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold']").InnerText;
              var condition = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h3[@class='a-spacing-small olpCondition']").InnerText;
              var price_shipping = item.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='olpShippingPrice']").InnerText;
              results += "price " + price + " condition " + condition + " ship " + price_shipping + "\r\n";
         }
    }
    return results;
```

No matter what combination I try of .// and . and ./ and / etc... I cannot get what I want (just now trying to learn xpaths), also currently it is returning just the 1st item over and over and over, just like the original question I referenced earlier.  I think I'm missing a fundamental understanding of how selecting nodes work and/or what is considered a node.

---

UPDATE

---

Ok, I've changed the URL to point to a different book and the first two items are working as expected...  When I try to change the third item (price_shipping) to a ".//" Absolutely no information is being pulled from anything.  This must be due to sometime there is not even a shipping price and that span is omitted.  How do I handle this?  I tried if price_shipping !=null.

---

UPDATE

---

Solved.  I removed the ".InnerText" from the price_shipping that causing issues when it was null... then I did the null check and Then it was safe to use .InnerText.

Comment: Are you linking the correct URL that you are parsing, because I cannot find neither of those elements on that page.

Comment: There didn't seem to be anything wrong with the URL, although when I clicked on it it gave the wrong page the First time only... I refreshed and it was the correct page.  I switched it to another book and loaded that URL and the first time it came to the right page.  There should be 10 book price listings.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the URL to point to a different book and the first two items are working as expected...  When I try to change the third item (price_shipping) to a ".//" Absolutely no information is being pulled from anything.  This must be due to sometime there is not even a shipping price and that span is omitted.  How do I handle this?  I tried if price_shipping !=null.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I removed the ".InnerText" from the price_shipping that causing issues when it was null... then I did the null check and Then it was safe to use .InnerText.